# How do I best store a shared key when implementing Open ID Connect implicit flow?

Tags: jwt, openid-connect

I am implementing Open Id Connect as the Relying Party using the 'implicit flow'. We are using the HS256 MAC based algorithm for signature.

As part of this implementation we need to generate a shared secret or key that is shared with both parties.

Is it safe to store this shared key in our database without hashing it? Normally we would hash and salt a password or API key but it seems that with the 'implicit flow' specified in Open Id Connect the secret is never sent across the wire, hence we would need to always be able to retrieve it again.

What is the best practice in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, if you have implemented Implicit Flow, you are using a public client.

In the Open ID Connect Specification [you can read in 10.1](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0-17.html#Signing) : **Symmetric signatures MUST NOT be used by public (non-confidential) Clients because of their inability to keep secrets.**

In this case, you must use a signing algorithm that uses asymetric key (RSA or EDCSA).